# Adding and removing events in javascript

Tags: javascript, events, simple-html-dom

I require to keep track on what events are on my dom elements and correspondingly add or remove event-listeners.

The way I keep track of the events right now is as follows ,

To add events :

```
function addListenerIfNone(addTo,eventType, func) {

    if(addTo.id){
        if (addedListeners[addTo.id+eventType]===eventType)
        {
            console.warn('event not added');
            return;

        }//event is alreaday present

        addedListeners[addTo.id+eventType]= eventType;

        addTo.addEventListener(eventType, func,true);
        console.warn('event added');
     
      
    }
    else{
        console.warn("Elements needs to have id attribute");
        return false;
    }
}
```

To remove added events:

```
function removeListenerIfPresent(addTo,eventType, func) {
    
    if(addTo.id){
        if (addedListeners[addTo.id+eventType]){ //event present
            addedListeners[addTo.id+eventType]= null;

            addTo.removeEventListener(eventType, func,true);
            console.warn("event  removed!");
            
        }
        else{
            console.warn("event not removed!");
            return false;
        }

       
    }
    else{
        console.warn("Elements needs to have id attribute");
        return false;
 

   }
}
```

I have a elements where I need to add click event dynamically as mousemoves overs it to different positions
My code(psuedo):

```
addListenerIfNone(ele,'mousemove',moveAttackFromHex);
    
    var moveAttackFromHex=function(e){
    if (e.pageY='someposition')
       {
        x='some value';
       }
    else
       {
        x='some other value';
       }
   function moveUnitHandler(){
                        unitObj.moveToAttackUnit(hexMeshObj.selectedUnit,x);
                    };


            
  removeListenerIfPresent(ele,'click', moveUnitHandler);     //this doesn't remove the event ,even tho it is present and I end up having lot of click events
                

  addListenerIfNone(ele,'click', moveUnitHandler);//add new event listener once the previous is removed
    }
```

I can't keep removeEvent after add event as I it would remove the event right away,

I don't want to use jquery as I have not used it for the entire project but as I last resort I may end up using it.

## note: the dom element already has a click event referencing another function,if this makes a difference but I think not..

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand ,a overall listener?

Comment: I believe you are creating a new moveUnitHandler instance every time. That is why your events are not being removed.

Comment: You can move your moveUnitHandler to the global namespace just to check

Comment: did that same result:(

Comment: Without seeing more of your code is difficult to say, but are you sure you are not having problems with hoisting? I tested here and it seems to work. You need to be sure you are not passing as an argument a variable that is not yet defined because of the hoisting process

Comment: In other words your moveAttackFromHex should be declared and initialized before you write the statement: addListenerIfNone(ele,'mousemove',moveAttackFromHex); And you also should keep the moveUnitHandler function as in the global namespace otherwise a new instance will be created every time and you will not be able to remove the listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code like it is would have problems with the javascript hoisting process. You also need to pass to the removeEventListener function the same callback you registered with the addEventListener function and that it doesn't seem to happen in your code since a new instance of an inner function is created every time in pure javascript.

```
addedListeners = {};
function addListenerIfNone(addTo, eventType, func) {
    if(addTo.id) {
        if (addedListeners[addTo.id+eventType] === eventType)
        {
            console.warn('event not added');
            return;

        }//event is alreaday present

        addedListeners[addTo.id+eventType]= eventType;

        addTo.addEventListener(eventType, func, true);
        console.warn('event added');
    }
    else{
        console.warn("Elements needs to have id attribute");
        return false;
    }
}


function removeListenerIfPresent(addTo, eventType, func) {
    if(addTo.id){
        if (addedListeners[addTo.id+eventType]){ //event present
            addedListeners[addTo.id+eventType]= null;

            addTo.removeEventListener(eventType, func, true);
            console.warn("event  removed!");

        }
        else{
            console.warn("event not removed!");
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{
        console.warn("Elements needs to have id attribute");
        return false;
   }
}

function moveUnitHandler() {
    console.log("moveUnitHandler");
};

var moveAttackFromHex = function(e) {
    console.log(addedListeners);
    if (e.pageY = 'someposition') {
        console.log("if");
    }
    else {
        console.log("else");
    }

    removeListenerIfPresent(ele, 'click', moveUnitHandler);
    addListenerIfNone(ele, 'click', moveUnitHandler);
}

var ele = document.getElementById("ele");
addListenerIfNone(ele, 'mousemove', moveAttackFromHex);
```

Obs: you probably also have a typo in the statement: if (e.pageY = 'someposition'), maybe it should be: if (e.pageY === 'someposition')